# Shari'a marriage with out paper work but with witness

Tags: nikah, fiqh

My friend wants marry a girl with out paper work. Both are agree about it and they have witness,too.Now my question is can they marry in Shari'a ?

Comment: Yes, the contract is a verbal agreement and doesn't need to have paperwork.

Answer (score -1):

Nikha didnt required paperwork. They both need witnesses for Maher issue.

Comment: Well you might be right but it would be nice to support your statement with references!